# Order of setting DataContext in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

Which one is the right way to set DataContext in code behind:

```
public ViewConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

or

```
public ViewConstructor()
{
    DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

?

Comment: Both are "right". However, if the view is a UserControl, you should not set its DataContext at all, because that would prevent inheriting a DataContext from the window or parent control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer is: *it depends*.

If your screen contains a lot of data or complex data-driven visualizations, you may want to defer or stagger its loading, which may make the first option better. If it's a simple data-bound form, the second option may be preferable. Or it may even be negligible. As always, *measuring* is the best way to answer the question under your specific conditions.

Let's see what happens by enabling tracing on a binding.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
</Window>
```

## First option - `InitializeComponent` first

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Initializing");
    InitializeComponent();
    Debug.WriteLine("Initialized");
    Debug.WriteLine("Setting DataContext");
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
    Debug.WriteLine("DataContext Set");
}
```

Here we see that during `InitializeComponent` (when the XAML is loaded) the bindings try to resolve, but see that the `DataContext` is null, so their evaluation is *deferred*.

Debug output:

```
Initializing
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=55924514) for Binding (hash=26055869)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'IsEnabled'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.Grid.IsEnabled (hash=21411931)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): Found data context element: Grid (hash=21411931) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): Resolve source deferred
Initialized
Setting DataContext
DataContext Set
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): Found data context element: Grid (hash=21411931) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): Activate with root item ViewModel (hash=45063479)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514):   At level 0 - for ViewModel.IsEnabled found accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsEnabled)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): Replace item at level 0 with ViewModel (hash=45063479), using accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsEnabled)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): GetValue at level 0 from ViewModel (hash=45063479) using ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsEnabled): 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): TransferValue - got raw value 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=55924514): TransferValue - using final value 'False'
```

## Second option - set `DataContext` first

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Setting DataContext");
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
    Debug.WriteLine("DataContext Set");
    Debug.WriteLine("Initializing");
    InitializeComponent();
    Debug.WriteLine("Initialized");
}
```

Here the bindings evaluate immediately during initialization.

Debug output:

```
Setting DataContext
DataContext Set
Initializing
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=27331439) for Binding (hash=41386841)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'IsEnabled'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.Grid.IsEnabled (hash=16919637)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439): Found data context element: Grid (hash=16919637) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439): Activate with root item ViewModel (hash=25445597)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439):   At level 0 - for ViewModel.IsEnabled found accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsEnabled)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439): Replace item at level 0 with ViewModel (hash=25445597), using accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsEnabled)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439): GetValue at level 0 from ViewModel (hash=25445597) using ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsEnabled): 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439): TransferValue - got raw value 'False'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=27331439): TransferValue - using final value 'False'
Initialized
```